# Manually scrolling UITableViewController when a UITextField becomes first responder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

Harrr pirates!

I'm trying to make a data entry screen using a `UITableViewController`. It contains a grouped table view with two sections, each with a few (2 and 4) rows with a `UITextField` inside them.
When any of the `UITextFields` become first responder they scroll into view automatically. Great, you would say, but I want to scroll the whole section into view, not just the row containing the `UITextField` that became first responder.
I don't allow the user to scroll the `UITableView` by hand and I know to what position it should scroll to display correctly. However, I can't get my `UITableViewController` to stop automatically scrolling the `UITextField` into view for me.

Searching StackOverflow I can find a lot of questions about how to resize the `UITableView` when the keyboard appears, but this doesn't stop the automatic scrolling.

Any suggestions? Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've figured it out now. I just shouldn't subclass from UITableViewController but instead use a UIViewController and manage a UITableView myself :)

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer to your question and accept it (yes, that's OK since it *is* the answer to the problem).

Answer (score 0):

TableView is basically an extension of `scrollView` therefore if you want to do the scroll yourself you should use the `scrollview` API.

Set the `contectSize` property to the size of the screen without the keyboard and the `contentOffset` to the location on the table you want to scroll to